# Impact of Mindstorms sets being discontinued?

Tags: mindstorms, software

I was given some Mindstorms sets a while ago and I'm waiting for my kids to grow up so they can use them. Does the recent announcement of their end mean it will brick (pun intended) the kit? Will the software parts still be available for download?

NOTE: I've never used Mindstorms yet, so I'm not sure what it involves.

Side question: are they being replaced by something else?

Comment: The questions about downloads being available and being replaced by something else aren't really answerable since, one, they can only be answered by LEGO and, two, the answer may change over time. This question could be improved be rewording it to only ask things that don't rely on speculation.

Comment: Which Mindstorms? The software used to come on CDs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mindstorms kits will work as well as they ever did, as long as you don't upgrade your computer to something incompatible. This happened before with the Serial IR base.

The software is so common now that it seems unlikely you'd ever not be able to find a download, likely from Lego themselves.

I've read that FIRST Lego League had effectively already moved to Spike Prime, but I can not yet spot any official statement to that effect.

Comment: Does the serial IR base work with USB-to-serial adapters?

Comment: <https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/183377-why-are-lego-rcx-sets-so-cheap/> implies that it will, even better than the USB tower.